# AngularJS how to access element in a template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular-ui's modal dialog control.

```
$uibModal.open({
    animation: false,
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TestController',
    size : 'lg'
});
```

When I implement the TestController, I will not be able to access elements in test.html, but will be able to access anything in the primary html, Like,

```
myApp.controller('TestController', function(){

   angular.element(document).ready(function(){
       var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
       console.log(inputs);//only prints inputs from the host html
   });

});
```

It will not find those "input"s from the template html. How do I do access those elements?

Comment: You can access the inputs with `ng-model`

Comment: I do not want to access its value actually. I have an <input type="file">. I want to add an onchange event to it. I guess I cannot use ng-model to add an event listener in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If you're able to access `document`, the root of the DOM tree, you'll be able to access anything that was loaded. So the real question is why `test.html` isn't being loaded.

Perhaps it's a relative path problem? Unless `test.html` is in your root directory, you'll need to specify the path to that file.

Comment: test.html is being loaded only when the angularJS brings up the dialog box. I guess when I am accessing the element, the test.html has not finished loading yet. I cannot use $document.ready() since the $document is the host html, which is already ready. I think if there is a $template.ready(), that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hm, I thought that the template would be available once the controller runs. What happens when you get rid of the `.ready` stuff in the controller?

Comment: When you inspect the DOM using the dev tools, is `test.html` there? Also, I wonder if there's something weird about inputs. What happens when you add `<div id="foo">` to `test.html` and try `document.getElementById('foo')` in `TestController`?

Comment: This does not answer the question and would be better suited as a comment. DOM selection should typically be avoided in Angular and he probably needs to use `ng-change` for the input or some other linked method / use data bindings.

Comment: I ended up using directive for linking the event listener. @ExplosionPills thanks I learn that I should avoid working on DOM element directly.

Comment: Cool. He's right about the best approach, and I should have thought to mention that. But as for what the question was explicitly asking, my understanding is that it's asking why the DOM elements in `template.html` aren't accessible in `TestController`, and if so I think I (tried to) address it.